# import shared_tasks in celery

Tags: python, task, celery

I tried to use a shared_task in my django project. But I'm not able to import them. I'm using Celery 4.1.0 (latentcall)

I will have the shared_task inside a **library** (now they are in a folder but a whl will be created) I'm searching in documentation, examples in internet but I don't find any.

In my django project I have: ***(look update bellow)***

But when I create the task:

```
app.send_task('futurelibrary.tasks.taskfunction', [])
```

but the result of the task is:

```
NotRegistered('futurelibrary.tasks.taskfunction')
```

I have read to put the import in `__init__.py` of the setting django folder. But I can't do this. I'll have different celery configurations and different library tasks.

I'm going to try different paths to find if maybe I'm using an incorrect one. I'll update if I find the solution.

**UPDATE**: There must be something I'm doing wrong because it doesn't discover tasks. I'm going to give you my actual structure and what I write as module:

```
myproject
│
├──futurelibrary
│  └──tasks.py
│
├──djangoappmain
│  ├──urls.py
│  └──[...]
│
├──djangoapp2
│  ├──celery.py
│  └──apps.py
│
└──settings
   ├──celeryconfig.py
   └──workerconf.py
```

Those are the only files inside each folder (but djangoappmain which has more files)

When I call the worker I do:

```
celery worker --config=settings.workerconf
```

Inside djangoapp2/celery I have:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery
from settings import celeryconfig

app = Celery('my_app')

app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)
# Write the module to import where task.py are
app.autodiscover_tasks(['futurelibrary'])
```

If you need also what are inside configfiles just tell me and I paste them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem:

Seems that I don't need really to discover task. I just need to add them into workerconf:

```
imports = ('futurelibrary.tasks', )
```

Everything is working now.